# Can i break the speed limit in space engineers without mods?

Tags: space-engineers

I was just wondering if it is possible to break the speed limit (104m/s) without using mods.  I tried using more thrusters but i think its not possible. I saw a *mod* which helps to achieve this but i really don't want to download one.

**Can planet's gravitational assist increase speed?**

Comment: I know that you used to be able to go faster than 104m/s using a gravity generator engine ("Warp drive"), but I think it may have been patched.

Comment: It might be possible using a rotor and a long enough arm, the end of the arm would move at the product of the angular velocity and the arm length. Haven't tested though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not. Even when you are accelerated by the gravity of a planet your speed maxes out at 104 m/s. You can easily check that by creating a new game with the "Star System" scenario which puts you into a lander free-falling towards the surface of a planet.

By the way, you can change the speed yourself without using mods by editing the file `SpaceEngineers\Content\Data\Environment.sbc` with a text editor. Just change the number 100 in these two lines to your liking:

```
<SmallShipMaxSpeed>100</SmallShipMaxSpeed>
<LargeShipMaxSpeed>100</LargeShipMaxSpeed>
```

Unfortunately every weekly update might overwrite your changes.

Comment: And no, I have no idea why the *actual* top-speed in the game is always slightly higher than the value in the Environment.sbc file. Must be some quirk of the physics engine.